# Log into local SSH shell over guacamole

Tags: ssh, localhost, guacamole

So I want to use guacamole to access the 127.0.0.1 ssh shell.

I have disabled plain text password auth and root login. Using a private for my normal ssh sessions.

Is there a way to allow localhost logins to be authenticated with password in the sshd config?

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC Guacamole supports public key authentication.

Comment: @DanielB So like you said, I did stick the priv key inside and then used both the localhost and ip address to connect. Both with and without user/password and other combos. None of them worked for some reason. But if I log in to localhost with the username and password field empty at least I can input the password. It could be that I am somehow missing the public key (base 64) value. But I have no idea how to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-enable it in a `Match` block.

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

Match Address ::1
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match Address 127.0.0.1
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Is the ::1 a must or is the 127.... by itself enough?

Comment: regardless if that is enough, sshd didn't start for me with only the Match block beginnings. There has to be an end. In this case I added the "Match All" line after the two things and sshd restarted successfully. Proceeded to log in via guac to local host and I got in successfully. Thank you!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67334/openssh-how-to-end-a-match-block

So either end it with what I said or place it at the end of the file. Good question to read up for those who are doing the same thing.

Comment: The ::1 is a "localhost" address just like 127.0.0.1 is. It usually makes sense to add both.